# RPi-PIC18 I2C: problem with first byte

Tags: pic, raspberry-pi, i2c, c, mplab

I am having a bit of a problem with RPi-PIC18 I2C communication. The raspberry is the master, the problem is with the PIC18F25K80 slave device. Here is my code regarding the I2C parts:

```
int i = 0;

void __interrupt() tc_int(void) {
    if (PIR1bits.SSPIF == 1) {
        PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0; /* clear interrupt flag */
        SSPCON1bits.CKP = 0; /* clock stretching is automatic, but to emphasize */
        if ((SSPCON1bits.SSPOV) || (SSPCON1bits.WCOL)) {  /* if overflow or collision */
            dummy = SSPBUF; /* clear buffer */
            SSPCON1bits.SSPOV = 0; /* reset overflow detection flag bit */
            SSPCON1bits.WCOL = 0; /* reset collision detection flag bit */
            LED1 = ~LED1;
        }
        if (!SSPSTATbits.R_nW) { /* master wants to write, slave must read */
            while (!SSPSTATbits.BF); /* wait for buffer to fill */
            if (!SSPSTATbits.D_nA) { /* this is the address */
                dummy = SSPBUF; /* discard address */
                byte_count = 0;
            }
            else { /* master sends data */
                data_in[byte_count++] = SSPBUF; /* read buffer */
            }
        }
        else { /* master wants to read, slave must write */
            if (!SSPSTATbits.D_nA) { /* this is the address */
                handle_i2c(); /* simple switch case that fills the output array */
                byte_count = 0;
                SSPBUF = i++;
            }
            else {
                SSPBUF = data_out[byte_count++];
            }
        }
        SSPCON1bits.CKP = 1; /* release clock */
    }
}

void init_i2c_slave() {
    SSPSTATbits.SMP = 1; /* slew rate control is disabled for standard speed mode */
    SSPCON1bits.SSPM = 0b0110; /* I2C slave mode, 7-bit address */
    SSPCON1bits.SSPEN = 1; /* SDA and SCL are configured for I2C <- SDA and SCL must be configured as inputs */
    TRISCbits.TRISC3 = 1; /* SDA and SCL configured as inputs */
    TRISCbits.TRISC4 = 1; /* SDA and SCL configured as inputs */
    /* clock stretching - after each received byte, the CKP (clock) is held low, must be released in software */
    SSPCON2bits.SEN = 1;

    SSPADD = (SLAVEADRESS << 1); 

    PIR1bits.SSPIF = 0; /* clear the slave interrupt flag */
    PIE1bits.SSPIE = 1; /* enable the master interrupt */
}

void init_isr() {
    RCONbits.IPEN = 1; /* interrupt priority levels are enabled */
    INTCONbits.GIE_GIEH = 1; /* global interrupt enable */
    INTCONbits.PEIE_GIEL = 1; /* peripheral interrupt enable */
    INTCONbits.TMR0IE = 0; /* no interrupt for timer 0 */
}
```

When the master writes, it works just fine, no problems there, the slave can read the bytes and do whatever it has to do with them in the main loop. But when the master wants to read, I have problems with the first byte that is wrote. I implemented it so that the "i" variable is written as the first byte to the master, it is initialized as 0 and is incremented each time it is written, so each time the master wants to read. But this is the what the master receives:

```
r <- y : 000 070 070
r <- y : 129 100 000 000 000 030 130
r <- y : 130 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 131 100 000 000 000 027 127
r <- y : 132 100 000 000 000 036 136
r <- y : 133 100 000 000 000 033 133
r <- y : 134 100 000 000 000 027 127
r <- y : 135 100 000 000 000 037 137
r <- y : 136 100 000 000 000 033 133
r <- y : 137 100 000 000 000 032 132
r <- y : 138 100 000 000 000 026 126
r <- y : 139 100 000 000 000 032 132
r <- y : 140 100 000 000 000 030 130
r <- y : 141 100 000 000 000 037 137
r <- y : 142 100 000 000 000 034 134
r <- y : 143 100 000 000 000 031 131
r <- y : 144 100 000 000 000 031 131
r <- y : 145 100 000 000 000 029 129
r <- y : 146 100 000 000 000 033 133
r <- y : 147 100 000 000 000 030 130
r <- y : 148 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 149 100 000 000 000 036 136
r <- y : 150 100 000 000 000 027 127
r <- y : 151 100 000 000 000 033 133
r <- y : 152 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 153 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 154 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 155 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 156 100 000 000 000 038 138
r <- y : 157 100 000 000 000 026 126
r <- y : 158 100 000 000 000 031 131
r <- y : 159 100 000 000 000 033 133
r <- y : 160 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 161 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 162 100 000 000 000 031 131
r <- y : 163 100 000 000 000 038 138
r <- y : 164 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 165 100 000 000 000 033 133
r <- y : 166 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 167 100 000 000 000 034 134
r <- y : 168 100 000 000 000 030 130
r <- y : 169 100 000 000 000 034 134
r <- y : 170 100 000 000 000 035 135
r <- y : 171 100 002 000 000 032 134
r <- y : 172 100 002 000 000 032 134
r <- y : 173 100 002 000 000 032 134
r <- y : 174 100 002 000 029 031 162
r <- y : 175 100 000 000 080 037 217
r <- y : 176 100 000 000 132 034 010
r <- y : 177 100 000 000 184 040 068
r <- y : 178 100 000 000 235 034 113
r <- y : 179 100 000 001 030 034 165
r <- y : 180 100 000 001 082 033 216
r <- y : 181 100 000 001 133 037 015
r <- y : 182 100 000 001 185 038 068
r <- y : 183 100 000 001 236 037 118
r <- y : 184 100 000 002 032 031 165
r <- y : 185 100 000 002 083 040 225
r <- y : 186 100 000 002 135 037 018
r <- y : 187 100 000 002 186 033 065
r <- y : 188 100 000 002 239 038 123
r <- y : 189 100 000 003 035 033 171
r <- y : 190 100 000 003 086 032 221
r <- y : 191 100 000 003 138 032 017
r <- y : 192 100 000 003 189 036 072
r <- y : 193 100 000 003 241 040 128
r <- y : 194 100 000 004 037 037 178
r <- y : 195 100 000 004 089 034 227
r <- y : 196 100 000 004 140 038 026
r <- y : 197 100 000 004 192 035 075
r <- y : 198 100 000 004 244 031 123
r <- y : 199 100 000 005 040 031 176
r <- y : 200 100 000 005 092 033 230
r <- y : 201 100 000 005 143 040 032
r <- y : 202 100 000 005 195 036 080
r <- y : 203 100 000 005 247 037 133
r <- y : 204 100 000 006 043 038 187
r <- y : 205 100 000 006 096 038 240
r <- y : 206 100 000 006 147 037 034
r <- y : 207 100 000 006 199 036 085
r <- y : 208 100 000 006 251 034 135
r <- y : 209 100 000 007 046 035 188
r <- y : 210 100 000 007 098 031 236
r <- y : 211 100 000 007 150 034 035
r <- y : 212 100 000 007 202 033 086
r <- y : 213 100 000 007 254 030 135
r <- y : 214 100 000 008 050 031 189
r <- y : 215 100 000 008 102 034 244
r <- y : 216 100 000 008 153 035 040
r <- y : 217 100 001 008 204 039 096
r <- y : 218 100 001 008 204 039 096
r <- y : 219 100 001 008 204 039 096
r <- y : 092 050 001 003 232 254 028
r <- y : 093 050 000 003 232 254 027
r <- y : 094 050 000 003 232 254 027
r <- y : 095 050 000 003 232 254 027
r <- y : 096 050 000 003 232 255 028
r <- y : 097 050 000 003 232 254 027
r <- y : 098 050 000 003 232 254 027
r <- y : 099 050 000 003 232 254 027
r <- y : 100 050 000 003 232 254 027
r <- y : 101 050 000 003 232 254 027
r <- y : 102 050 000 003 232 254 027
```

As you can see, the first byte starts off as "0", since the initial value of "i" is "0". But after that, when the value of "i" is "1", the first byte is "129" and not "1", so instead of "0b00000001", "0b10000001" is sent. And I do not know why. And the funny thing is that it seems to me that this depends on the next byte that is sent. Because if the sencond byte turns to 50 from 100, this phenomena is gone, and the actual value of "i" is sent, that is "92".

I am a bit lost on why this happens or what the problem is. Maybe I am setting some flags falsely, maybe the whole thing is wrong, I have no idea.

Comment: have you tried to manually send 3-4 commands without any loops? write the data you wanna send manually. all manually. purely for debug. check stuff values after increments (blink LED if i==2 or something). I also use while(1) loops to halt the code at some point. Say, right after you were supposed to blink LED if everything is correct. So no blink => something's off. That's how I debug this stuff sometimes. I also have a 140$ logic analyzer LA2016, which helped IMMEASURABLY (my first LA) to debug UART and I2C

Comment: some weird stuff may occur when you turn slave address ready for sending when you shift it 1 bit to incorporate read/write bit? also check if there's anything with least and most significant bits first? maybe you flip something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I am still nut sure what black magic this was, but I added a small delay before releasing the clock int the ISR and I also reduced the master clock speed and now it seems to work. Also I forgot to clear the buffer when the master wants to read and the byte was the address. Now it seems to work...